# Example of a countable open set of real numbers?

Tags: general-topology

I am unable to think of a set that is both open and countable. While I can easily think of several that are not-closed and countable, finding explicitly open ones (besides the empty set) is proving to be difficult for me. Are there any?

Comment: With the Euclidean topology, no. With other topologies yes.

Comment: @Milly That should be expanded into an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are none; by definition a subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if to each point $x\in U$ there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x\in (a,b)\subset U$.  Since you are requiring $U$ to be non-empty, this means that the cardinality of $U$ would have to be the same as that of $\mathbb{R}$ since it contains an open interval.

Answer (score 7):

It is necessarily difficult. An open set is the union of open intervals and already a single open interval has continuum-many elements. Hence the empty set is the only example.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $A$ is open and $a\in A$, then $A$ contains an interval about $a$.